# Removing land based cells from sea surface temperature grid by using shoreline shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am a second year Geo student.

I was tasked with creating a sea surface temperature grid from a colour profile, which I have completed, but I am required to drop the land based cells through the use of a shoreline shapefile.

I have dissolved the shoreline (which I am hoping is the right move), but can't seem to find a way to move forward.

Comment: What were the precise steps that you performed to create your sea surface temperature grid from your colour profile, and then what happened when you dissolved the shoreline?  I think it would be useful if you included a picture of precisely where you are up to.

Comment: I figured it out tonight. My problem was not specifying the tolerance when using the Feature to Raster tool on the polyline shore file.  Used 100m and it came out great.  Dissolve was unnecessary.  Thanks for the help.